# Conditionnal Background Color LibreOffice Calc

Tags: libreoffice, colors

I have a spreadsheet to keep track of which pokemon I already collected. On a second work sheet I have a diagram that shows which pokemon evolves in what other pokemon. On the first sheet I have the pokemon I have marked by a different background color. Is it possible to make the background color of the cells on the second worksheet dependant on the background color of the corresponding cells in the first work sheet?

Comment: If your question doesn't get much attention on AskUbuntu.com you can also post it on AskLibreOffice.com. Yes you can have Sheet2 reference Sheet1 formats. I don't have enough experience to post a good answer.

Comment: Do you mean http://ask.libreoffice.org/questions/?